# Dangling participle?

Tags: sentence-structure, participles

As far as I know those two examples below considered wrong because of dangling participles.

> 1- For the interview, William borrowed Grandpa's old suit,
>   ***draped*** neatly on a hanger.
>
> 2- Do you know my brother Ben, ***living*** in Hong Kong.

To make them correct, I should rewrite them as:

> 1'- For the interview, William borrowed Grandpa's old suit, ***which
>   was draped*** neatly on a hanger.
>
> 2'- Do you know my brother Ben, ***who lives*** in Hong Kong.

My question is that why those sentences below aren't considered wrong?

> 3-  Did you read Hamlet, ***written*** by William Shakespeare? (which
>   was written)
>
> 4- The critic used "spins out", ***meaning*** to lengthen,
>   adjacent to the resulting length, thus emphasizing the number of
>   pages. (which means)

Comment: 1) and 2) are not incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid your prior assumption is incorrect. These are not "dangling participles".  These are just ordinary participles.

Many participles, like those in (1-4), are formed from reducing relative clauses, like those in (1'-2'). They are not ungrammatical, and the participles in (1-2) are not "dangling". (3-4) are similar in structure, and there's nothing grammatically wrong with them, either; nor do they "dangle".

The construction that's condemned as a "dangling participle" has to be a participle that lacks a subject. Most participles do, but it's easy to see what the subjects would be in (1-4), because the participles come right after them. That's not "dangling" -- that's being properly placed.

Besides being subjectless, a "dangling participle" has to be placed in the sentence in a way that points to an incorrect subject. Since subjectless participle phrases often are adverbial in meaning, they can be moved around, by various rules, viz:

- *Three cats were sitting on a fence.*
- *Sitting on a fence were three cats.*
- *There were three cats sitting on a fence.*
- *Sitting on a fence there were three cats.*

But this can isolate a participle from its subject, especially if the sentence is complex:

- *My grandmother saw three cats sitting on a fence.*
- *[Sitting on a fence] my grandmother saw three cats.*

These last two sentences don't mean the same thing, and the bracketed part is an example of a real "dangling participle". The "dangle" part of the metaphor refers to the unfilled subject slot of the participle, which gets attached to the wrong noun, like a dangling chain caught on an obstruction.

As one can see from the example, dangling participles are the basis of many jokes.

Comment: Thanks, the reason why I was wrong in classifying the first two participle as dangling participle is that I asked those sentences to another native speakers and they said: In number 1, I think you need "which was" to be inserted before "draped," because the sentence seems unclear as to what "draped" modifies. In number 2, who’s living in Hong Kong – “you” or Ben?

Comment: Native speakers' intuitions about grammaticality are likely to be confused with meaning oddities because Anglophone schools don't teach real English grammar and therefore people get very odd ideas about what's grammatical. There are two ways to pronounce (2); in one of them, _living in Hong Kong_ means "while you are/were living in Hong Kong"; the other way it means Ben lives/d there. Written sentences are always ambiguous, depending on pronunciation. In (1), the _which was_ is deletable by [_Whiz_-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299).

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask one more question if possible, "Essos is an immense landmass located to the east of Westeros, extending into the far east of the known world." (Here, "extending" describes the Essos not Westeros, but it is used right after Westeros. Is it considered as misplaced participle or just bad writing?)

Comment: Neither. _A landmass_ is just a predicate noun phrase with two participial modifiers -- _located ... Westeros_, and _entending ... world._ They have to appear in **some** order, after all; they can't be simultaneous.

Comment: Hi again me. If possible, I would like to ask something. Can I use participles to modify the subject of the main clause when there is no connection between main clause and participle clause. For example: "He is a bookworm, ***living*** in Canada. (He is a bookworm + He lives in Canada, there is no connection between being bookworm and living in Canada)

Comment: Participial phrases or clauses are multi-word modifiers, and multi-word modifers go after the word they modify. There doesn't have to be some "connection" between successive modifiers, as long as they both modify the same thing. Grammar is about forms, not meanings.

Comment: @Lambie I appreciate your help :). But this topic was created ten days ago.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Ok, I see. I just don't see why it came up at the top of the list. As it did, I didn't look at the date.

Comment: @JohnLawler Could you help me out in my new thread ? (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215775/participles-to-modify-the-subject-of-the-main-clause-when-the-verb-of-the-main-c)